# Getting HTTP stream is blocking rendering

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm downloading a stream from a WebAPI and I'm trying to run code while the stream is being read.

The code below works fine on Blazor server-side or an console app. But on blazor-client side the stream will first download fully before executing any code.... even just a Console.WriteLine() will just start writing to Console after the stream is done. 
I'm using the latest .Net Core 3.0 Preview 8...

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<SomeClass> GetDataAsync()
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using (var stream = await Http.GetStreamAsync("https://localhost:44334/api/values/i"))
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            while (await jr.ReadAsync()) //<-- Stream is fully download to browser before taking any actions.
            {
                if (jr.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray && jr.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(jsonReader.LinePosition);
                    yield return serializer.Deserialize<SomeClass>(jr);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this with WireShark to confirm that this is happening.

Is this by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this by design?

**I guess it is currently by design** !

this will not block simply because the async / await pattern is supported in client-side Blazor. It seems to me that the real issue is with HttpClient.GetStreamAsync, as the HttpClient service (client-side Blazor) is not the actual or real HttpClient. It is based on the JavaScript Fetch Api (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Services/Http.ts):

```
responseData = await response.arrayBuffer();
```

> But if they switch to the mono implementation
>   (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10489), streaming will be
>   support if the browser supports it:
>   https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/254d6d37580a70fbb4fa072b0b2b16d2984b3bb5/sdks/wasm/framework/src/WebAssembly.Net.Http/WasmHttpMessageHandler.cs#L171-L173
>
> A call to arrayBuffer() will never return from a pure stream. A
>   different MessageHandler based on [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams#Consuming_a_fetch_as_a_stream)  would have to be
>   implemented, but I'm pretty sure it's not enough to just implement a
>   new message handler in this case.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, It sure confirms what I suspected. As far as Web Workers how would that be implemented with Blazor-client side? Any simple pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Never done it before...however, you can search google for this. Here are two links about the subject:  https://github.com/roboriaan/BlazorServiceWorker https://medium.com/@k.l.mueller/create-progressive-web-apps-with-net-using-blazor-6aa719e38000

Comment: ReadAsync _should_ be possible. Nothing in the code tries to create a thread. I think [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) could/should apply here too. Apparently it is not (yet) implemented this way.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That is what I don't understand. What's the point of using await / async in ```await Http.GetStreamAsync``` if it is blocking the browser.

Comment: @Charlie,  this will not block simply because the async / await pattern is supported in client-side Blazor. It seems to me that the real issue is with HttpClient.GetStreamAsync, as the HttpClient service (client-side Blazor) is not the actual or real HttpClient. It is based on the JavaScript Fetch Api (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Services/Http.ts). As I type this comment, I start to believe that it is the culprit. I'll post this question in github; perhaps they have a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: The current built-in `HttpClient` is very simplistic and based on `fetch` and `response.arrayBuffer()` [(source)](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/e0f95cfa6feec402ea34a605965f356720006513/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Services/Http.ts#L26) . A call to arrayBuffer() will never return from a pure stream.

A different MessageHandler based on [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams#Consuming_a_fetch_as_a_stream) would have to be implemented, but I'm pretty sure it's not enough to just implement a new message handler in this case.

Comment: Thanks, @Tewr, I've copied a part of your comment into my answer in order to make it complete...